# {integer contains some power of 2} function

Tags: r

I have a number that represents the states of an object, and I want to check for one of the states. For example, if the number is "22", it should return true when it checks for 16, 4, or 2, and false for anything else.
My function is

```
containsOrderType <- function(orderType, state) #returns whether the bitmask translates to containing that order type
{
  state <- as.numeric(state)
  if(orderType>state) return(FALSE)
  binState <- as.integer(state)
  class(binState) <- "binmode"
  binState <- as.character(binState)
  dim(binState) <- dim(state)
  X<-log2(orderType)+1
  if(str_sub(binState,-X,-X)==1) return(TRUE)
  return(FALSE)
}
```

this was working fine for a month until today, and I'm pretty sure that the problem is that dim(state) is taking dim([an integer]) which appears to always be "NULL". This has happened in R 2.15.3 and R 3.0.1.
I get it if thats consistant, but this function was working exactly as intended for a while, and now it doesn't.
Here is the intToBin function in R.Utils, which is identical to lines 3-6 of my function.

```
function (x) 
{
    y <- as.integer(x)
    class(y) <- "binmode"
    y <- as.character(y)
    dim(y) <- dim(x)
    y
}
```

also

```
>dim
function (x)  .Primitive("dim")
> class
function (x)  .Primitive("class")
```

so those haven't been overwritten by packages or anything weird like that.

Comment: You are trying to reinvent the wheel, in a really square way.

Comment: super cool dude, way to be constructive. Thanks for the vote down for no reason. It was a legitimate question.

Comment: if its "the wheel", where's the simple function?

Comment: It's in package `bitops`.

Comment: Are you referring to the function Martin brought up (before you said anything)? Well we can't all know where every function is. If you have something to add to the discussion, please do so in a respectful manner, like Martin Morgan did below. If you don't, then stop trolling.

Comment: I did not intend to troll. My point was that what you're trying to do (bit manipulation) is older than punched cards, and has been implemented efficiently in this package and many others. Your approach is poorly implemented. That *is* constructive, although a little bit picky, I confess. Anyway, better flag all this discussion for deletion, since SO is no place for silly disputes. Just one more thing: don't get so jealous of your code. :-)

Comment: Telling me its poorly implemented is fine, voting me down for asking a question I don't know the answer to is pointless

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `bitwAnd` function in base R, for example

```
> bitwAnd(22, 2^(0:10))
 [1]  0  2  4  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0
> bitwAnd(1:22, 16)
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 16 16 16 16 16 16
> bitwAnd(4, 2060)
[1] 4
> (bitwAnd(8, 2060) != 0) == containsOrderType(8, 2060)
> TRUE
```

or `bitAnd` in the [bitops](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bitops/index.html) package.

Comment: This function is restricted to small numbers. it cannot find fun(4,2060) (which is TRUE) for example.

Comment: @hedgedandlevered use `bitops::bitAnd()` if you're restricted to R-2.15.x

Comment: the fact that the function doesn't work makes the version compatibility not really an issue

Comment: bitops::bitAnd(8,2060) returns 8, which does not help me know that fun(8,2060) should be FALSE

Comment: @hedgedandlevered But `containsOrderedType(8, 2060)` returns TRUE, too?

Comment: My mistake, it should return true.
Alright, so I retract my issues with this part of what would be the greater function I would need to return the desired results. However, I had already answered this question by providing the entire function...

Comment: @hedgedandlevered different ways to skin a cat, I guess. I posted my solution because your solution loads some relatively 'heavy' dependencies, it seemed round-about to make a string representation to test a binary attribute, because the single function call (plus test for equality to 0) replaced your several lines of code, and because the `bitwAnd` solution acts on vectors, which we know is good in in R.

Answer (score 0):

apparently I moved some stuff around in my program and somehow didn't include R.utils itself... strange because I thought I copied the code in so I would have to include that package.
Anyway, I'll leave this up in case anyone else needs it.
Since I'm including the package anyway, my code can be simplified to:

```
containsOrderType <- function(orderType, state) #returns whether the bitmask translates to containing that order type
{
  state <- as.numeric(state)
  if(orderType>state) return(FALSE)
  binState <- intToBin(as.integer(state))
  X<-log2(orderType)+1
  if(str_sub(binState,-X,-X)==1) return(TRUE)
  return(FALSE)
}
```

Comment: This relies on functions in several packages; add the appropriate library calls to your solution.

Comment: true. `library(stringr)` (and `library(R.utils)` as previously mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gmp::factorize` as:

```
Rgames> 2%in%as.numeric(factorize(20))
[1] TRUE
```

Just be aware that `gmp` functions return `bigz` class stuff, which is why

```
Rgames> 2%in%factorize(20)
[1] FALSE
```

happens.

To answer hedgeandlevered's comment-- if you want the maximum power of `2` for your number, then

```
Rgames> 2^(sum(factorize(20)==2))
[1] 4
```

Will do that for you. (notice also that `==` coerces its arguments to a common class here)